# Two Rows into one row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had an output for the following like this in sQL server 2008.

```
select ItemCode,
case when trntype = 'Issued' then sum(qty) end as issuedqty,
case  when trntype = 'Received' then sum(qty) end as receievedqty
from  [View_New]
group by ItemCode,trntype
Order by itemcode 

Code            Recd Qty   Issued Qty
--------------------------------------
10CMSQURSET     NULL       2.0000
10CMSQURSET     56.0000    NULL
```

How will i display these rows into one Row:

```
Code            Recd Qty   Issued Qty
--------------------------------------
10CMSQURSET 56.0000     2.0000
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group only by item code and put the CASE inside the SUM:

```
select ItemCode,
   sum(case when trntype = 'Issued' then qty else 0 end) as issuedqty,
   sum(case  when trntype = 'Received' then qty else 0 end) as receievedqty
from  [View_New]
group by ItemCode
Order by itemcode
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use `PIVOT()` function

```
SELECT  itemCode,
        Received AS RECEIEVEDQTY,
        Issued AS ISSUEDQTY
FROM
        (
            SELECT  itemCode, trntype, qty
            FROM    View_new
        ) dta
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM(qty)
            FOR trntype IN ([Issued], [Received])
        ) pvt
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baa96/2)