# Select two rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a report of latest email changes from a transaction table and I'm currently getting results like this:

```
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|    Date    |  Time  | Acct |    Name    |   EmailOld   |   EmailNew   | ChangeType |
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 2019-10-11 | 8:05AM | 1234 | John Smith |              | John@new.com | INSERT     |
| 2019-10-11 | 8:04AM | 1234 | John Smith | John@old.com |              | DELETE     |
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

That I would like to combine into one result like this:

```
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
|    Date    |  Time  | Acct |    Name    |   EmailOld   |   EmailNew   | ChangeType |
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| 2019-10-11 | 8:05AM | 1234 | John Smith | John@old.com | John@new.com | UPDATE     |
+------------+--------+------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

I've tried building around this: 
[Two Rows into one row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784557/two-rows-into-one-row-in-sql)

and this:
[Format Two Rows into One Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898599/format-two-rows-into-one-row)

But they're dealing with numeric values and won't work for my situation.

Here's what my SQL is like when pulling from the database so far:

```
SELECT Date, Time, Acct, Name, EmailOld, EmailNew,
CASE
WHEN EmailOld = '' AND EmailNew <> '' THEN 'INSERT'
WHEN EmailOld <> '' AND EmailNew = '' THEN 'DELETE'
ELSE 'UPDATE'
END AS ChangeType,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY Date, Time) AS RowNum
FROM EmailChanges
```

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to get the table to format correctly when copying from the ASCII table generator.

Comment: What is the logic you decide for change type?

Comment: Can you explain how an INSERT and a DELETE makes an UPDATE? You need to provide the actual data here. [mcve]

Comment: How does column `ChangeType` value magically transform from INSERT and DELETE to UPDATE

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data from the `EmailChanges` table.

Comment: Sample data needs to include MORE than one change on a day, with close but different times.  Will INSERT always  precede  DELETE or could it be reversed? Will the proposed solutions work with this new data?

Comment: First of all you should make it clear that what is your purpose of this query,after that you should be using group by based on your aggregation factor,you want to combine multiple records into one record,Its okay, but based on what?based on date name email or other fields? to get what you want, the first step is knowing what you are exactly looking for.

Comment: @Eric basically, I have a transaction in the table where the old email address is getting removed and no new email address is getting submitted so I'm labeling those as DELETE. Then the next transaction is the new email address getting submitted so I'm labeling them as INSERT. I'd like to just combine those two transactions into one transaction as UPDATE.

Comment: @SeanLange what's happening is sometimes our users aren't adding the new email address when updating their email. They're deleting it out, then saving, then entering a new email address. Which is causing 2 transactions to show up in the table. I'm just trying to account for these changes.

Comment: You do realize that it is confusing to name an update "delete" right? So do you have some kind of window to merge these together? Meaning is it considered one row if you change the email to an empty string and then change it again to an email address a week later? Or is it only considered one row when the two actions occur within x minutes of each other? You need to provide some better sample data and explanation. The code for this isn't all that difficult but the question just isn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone, I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
with ins as (
select * from YourTable where ChangeType = 'INSERT'
)
, del as (
select * from YourTable where ChangeType = 'DELETE'
)
select Date, Time, Acct, Name
, EmailOld = iif(ins.EmailOld = '', del.EmailOld, ins.EmailOld)
, EmailNew = iif(ins.EmailNew = '', del.EmailNew, ins.EmailNew)
, ChangeType = 'UPDATE'
from ins 
    inner join del on del.Acct = ins.Acct
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how things are recorded in the EmailChanges table. For these records, I would assume that the transactions were implemented as follows:

- Email removed, row updated
- New Email added, row updated.

Now I have to make some assumptions here to make sense of this. I have to assume that the emails are being stored in a separate table, with one row per email, and for historical purposes you are flagging the old email address as deleted (instead of actually removing the email record) when you change an email address, then immediately adding the new email address.  This is a good pattern, and allows you to track email addresses and address changes for customers.

However, if the logging is done by trigger, then this is the pattern that occurs, because two separate operations have been run. (If this logging is being done programmatically, then change how the program logs updates.)

As I said, I am making assumptions, but they are reasonable assumptions for the situation described above. To make these into an UPDATE instead, you have a few different methods, none of which are certain to capture the update correctly - except one. The method I would use would be to create an INSTEAD OF trigger on an UPDATE to the email address. This would, within one transaction, flag the old email address as DELETED, add the new email address record, and log an UPDATE transaction into the table. Then, instead of performing two separate calls for updating the email address, (UPDATE ... SET Deleted, INSERT), your code performs one action (UPDATE), then the INSTEAD OF trigger handles the details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this-

```
SELECT [Date],[Time],Acct, [Name],EmailOld,EmailNew,
CASE
WHEN EmailOld <> '' AND EmailNew <> '' AND EmailOld<>EmailNew THEN 'UPDATE'
WHEN EmailOld = '' AND EmailNew <> '' THEN 'INSERT'
WHEN EmailOld <> '' AND EmailNew = '' THEN 'DELETE'
END AS ChangeType FROM 
(
SELECT [Date], MAX([Time]) AS [Time], Acct, [Name],
LTRIM(RTRIM(STRING_AGG(EmailOld,''))) AS EmailOld,LTRIM(RTRIM(STRING_AGG(EmailNew,''))) AS EmailNew
FROM EmailChanges
GROUP BY [Date],Acct,[Name]
) T;
```